# How to load all tabs in the background

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF (and computer science in general) and I was given a small project from my boss where there are 5 tabs, each that go to a different site. After logging in, the user is directed to the website of the 1st tab. In the background, the 4 other tabs should be loading in the background.

Each  has the following name: "tabItem1", "tabItem2", "tabItem3", "tabItem4" up to "tabItem5"
Inside each  there is a  up to "webBrowser5".

I think that I have to use threading to load the pages in the background, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I tried creating 4 different threads in the MainWindow such as:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     Thread thread1 = new Thread(Update1);
     thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread1.Start();

     Thread thread2 = new Thread(Update2);
     thread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread2.Start();

     Thread thread3 = new Thread(Update3);
     thread3.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread3.Start();

     Thread thread4 = new Thread(Update4);
     thread4.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread4.Start();
}

private void Update1()
    {
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          (ThreadStart)delegate()
              {
                tabItem2.Focus();
              }
          );
    }

private void Update2()
    {
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          (ThreadStart)delegate()
              {
                tabItem3.Focus();
              }
          );
    }

//...Goes up to Update4
```

This seems to only focus on the last thread and also it doesn't do it the background. I appreciate any guidance and help. Thanks!

Comment: You are starting 4 threads, all of which immediately invoke *back to the UI thread* just to set focus to a tab, and then immediately exit.  All of the real work is being done on the UI thread, as it must since you are interacting with controls.  What were you expecting to happen?  My guess is that you need to perform some kind of data loading on each tab.  Can you show us how that data is loaded?

Comment: doing Focus will just focus you to each tab one by one, but it will be so fast that you will only see the last operation. you need to load the web browser with a specific url?

Comment: @ChrisShain I'm not 100% sure how the data is loaded, but I think they are just links to different websites. Here is what each grid item looks like in the xaml files: <Grid>
                    <WebBrowser Height="Auto" Name="webBrowser2" Width="Auto"  LoadCompleted="webBrowser2_LoadCompleted" Navigated="webBrowser2_Navigated" />
                </Grid>

Comment: @Clueless Yes I think each tab is a web browser on its own and they each go to different links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That IS what the dispatcher is doing, operating on the main thread. You told the main thread to set focus because the object is on the main thread.

**The problem:**

The answer lies in why you must do this. **You cannot operate on a windows control in any other thread than the thread it was created on.** You also can't create a control in one thread, and set it as a child of a control in another thread.

What this means to you... is that what your boss asked you to do can't be done. The only thing you can do in the background is calculate algorithms. At best, you'll be able to load *data*, and operate on *data*, and interpret *data*, but if you want to have that data be displayed in, or converted into, windows controls, you must do that on the main thread.

**The only solution:**

However, you can have multiple UIThreads. Which means you can create multiple `Window`s. So, the must-do alternative is to create windows on separate threads for each tab content, then host the thread-windows on each tab.

[Threading windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)

[Host process window](http://www.equals-forty-two.com/2010/11/19/host-a-process-window-in-wpf/)

[Cross thread hosting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/10/26/hosting-wpf-ui-cross-thread-and-cross-process.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I'm guessing I will have 5 different xaml files for each tab?

Comment: @J-Y Not just 5 different xaml files, 5 different windows. But they can be defined in xaml (you could use the same xaml for each window but give it a different target website). The key point is to create the window in a separate thread, get it's handle, then create a window host in each tab on the main thread. Then host the threaded window in the window host. You should set the window to borderless, because a hosted window's border shows up.

Answer (score -2):

I do not agree with Xaade, I think you can do what you need using only this code:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
        //  load the pages
}), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
```

That code will be executed in background, so, there you can load every webBrowser you need.

You just need to specify the DispatcherPriority to `Background`.

Comment: Hi ty for the help. Whats the built-in function to load the pages?  Sorry about that, pretty beginner with all this C# and WPF.

Comment: Hi, you can use the `Source` property of the webBrowser

Comment: I'm getting an error when I put webBrowser2.Source; in the dispatcher method. "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: That message is shown when your syntax is wrong, perhaps it would be helpful to get some book of C sharp. But talking about the webBrowser, you can try something like the following: `myBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"))`

Comment: -1 Try his update code, but replace the entire Update1 method, without the invoke, with a [WebBrowser].Navigate call. [Code paste here](http://codetidy.com/3161/). It will crash, because you can't perform on the webBrowser on a separate thread. All your code does is redirect to the main ui thread, which doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Xaade, I dont know what you're talking about. What do you mean with "All my code"?? I never suggested using other "threads". You are not seeing my answer? Or, You downvoted just because I do not agree with you?

Comment: @Dante He wants to load all five pages at once. You absolutely need multiple threads for that. And if you use the Dispatcher without a target, it actually uses this.Dispatcher, which means you're executing that code on the main UI thread no matter the DispatcherPriority. Which means he'll still load the five pages one at a time. The only way to interact with controls simultaneously is to have them on the separate threads.

Comment: @Dante The only way to have them on separate threads is to put them in a window on a separate thread, and host the window.

Comment: @Xaade Yes, now I know you misunderstood his question, he never said that he wanted to load all five pages at once. Perhaps it would be worthy that you read the question again. Well, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @Dante Ok, if you don't believe me, take any project you have, use your method, but instead of loading pages, do a Thread.Sleep(10000); which is 10 seconds. Let me know if you can interact with your program.